# Libvirt routing between two NAT networks

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, libvirt

I have following two networks,

```xml
<network>
  <name>subsys-network</name>
  <bridge name="virbr1"/>
  <forward mode="nat"/>
  <ip address="192.168.72.1" netmask="255.255.255.128">
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.72.2' end='192.168.72.126'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

```xml
<network>
  <name>gw-frontend-network</name>
  <bridge name="virbr2"/>
  <forward mode="nat"/>
  <ip address="172.22.10.1" netmask="255.255.255.128">
    <dhcp>
      <range start='172.22.10.2' end='172.22.10.126'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`

I could find the option of using a [routed network](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#routed-network-config) but that would not have NAT for external network access.

How can I configure routing such that VMs on two networks can communicate with each other?

Currently trying to ping `172.22.10.64` from `192.168.72.56` returns following,

```
PING 172.22.10.64 (172.22.10.64) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.72.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.72.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.72.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
From 192.168.72.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
```

Comment: You need to set up NAT rule on the host so that it doesn't do NAT for all addresses, but excludes the address ranges of the private networks. Then you need to make sure there aren't firewall rules that prevent traffic between these two networks.

Comment: So what's currently happening is that it does NAT for all addresses outside the subnet. Got it. Is there a way to configure it within libvirt API?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with libvirt, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually add the necessary firewall rules to allow communication between these two networks. You need to make two changes:

1. Disable masquerading between the two networks, and
2. Allow forwarding between the two networks

To fix (1), we need to add a pair of rules to that `nat` `POSTROUTING` chain (before the call to the `LIBVIRT_PRT` chain). So perhaps:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 192.168.72.0/25 -d 172.22.10.0/25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 172.22.10.0/25 -d 192.168.72.0/25 -j ACCEPT
```

To fix (2), we need rules in the `filter` `FORWARD` chain before calls to the `LIBVIRT_FWI` or `LIBVIRT_FWO` chains:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 172.22.10.0/25 -d 192.168.72.0/25 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 192.168.72.0/25 -d 172.22.10.0/25 -j ACCEPT
```

Making those rules persistent is left as an exercise, since exactly how one does that varies by distribution and by firewall management tool.

Answer (score 0):

You may just delete the rules blocking ICMP echo (causing the "Destination Port Unreachable" response) as such:

```
iptables -D LIBVIRT_FWI 2
iptables -D LIBVIRT_FWO 2
```

There is no sign of anything being wrong with your routing, it's just libvirt that blocks ICMP packets by default for some reason. It looks like this on my machine:

```
Chain LIBVIRT_FWI (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/16        ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain LIBVIRT_FWO (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  172.16.0.0/16        anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

The two above commands will just delete these two chains. larsks' solution is probably more elegant since it will modify the chains to allow forwarding, but just deleting them is also an option.